# How to install / connect Excel to SAP HANA via MDX

Tags: excel, hana

Connecting Excel to SAP HANA is very easy if the MDX Driver is already known to Excel.

There are so many Tutorials that explain how to do it. But not how to install the driver.

Please note the the HANA Client is not available any more.

So how to install the MDX driver?

The official download link is also broken:
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/webcontent/uuid/402aa158-6a7a-2f10-0195-f43595f6fe5f

Answer (score 2):

The SAP HANA Client is still available but very difficult to find.

I got the hint from a recent SCN Entry: [How to access HANA using Excel?](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2016/01/01/how-to-access-hana-using-excell)

Unfortunately I did not succeed using the description. But **using the search function on on the software download center** I finally found the client.

Most of the other links like http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/00/6cc8dc05b2404cb6148493f854b7cb/content.htm?frameset=/en/68/f5b289fab2427e9580a4524071ba96/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/c5/938573bb571014a4abd04d9059e2bd/plain.htm&node_id=6&show_children=false

are utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the S-ID to log into support.sap.com and download the HANA Client (just search the keywords in the SAP portal) in order to use the MDX driver. But if you only intend to fetch data from HANA to Excel and do not have to work with analytical views or calculated views, you can use the free AecorSoft Reporting HANA Edition to work with HANA, which supports catalog objects like Table, View, Synonym. The analytical view will be supported in next release.

Disclaimer: the product mentioned here is our company's offering. It is completely free, not trial.